# How can I employ "if exists" for creating or dropping an index in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I was wondering if there's a way to check if an index exists before creating it or destroying it on MySQL. It appears that there was a feature request for this a few years back, but I can't find any documentation for a solution. This needs to be done in a PHP app using MDB2.

Comment: Use recent MariaDB, which supports IF EXISTS

Answer (score 62):

Here is my 4 liner:

```
set @exist := (select count(*) from information_schema.statistics where table_name = 'table' and index_name = 'index' and table_schema = database());
set @sqlstmt := if( @exist > 0, 'select ''INFO: Index already exists.''', 'create index i_index on tablename ( columnname )');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: As someone who loads multiple databases with the same schema, I'd add to the WHERE on the first line: "AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()"

Comment: @VenerableAgents, I just edited the answer to contain that. Saved my life here :)

Comment: This answer is great if you don't want to deal with any stored procedures.

Comment: I think i should read :table_schema = 'database'  

 rather than 

table_schema = database()

Comment: Any idea why we cant do  if( @exist > 0, 'create index i_index on tablename ( columnname )'); ?

Answer (score 30):

`IF EXISTS` modifier is not built for `DROP INDEX` or `CREATE INDEX` yet. But you can check manually for the existence before creating/dropping an index.

Use this sentence to check whether the index already exists.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table_name WHERE KEY_NAME = 'index_name'
```

- If the query returns zero (0) then the index does not exists, then you can create it.
- If the query returns a positive number, then the index exists, then you can drop it.

Comment: This query does not work for me. If I delete the WHERE clause it works, but then it is not very helpful. A KEY_name column does get displayed when I delete the WHERE clause though.

Comment: I just checked again to make sure, and worked for me. Maybe it's a version or configuration issue. I'm using version 5.1.45.

Comment: @PabloVenturino can this be checked "programatically" within an SQL statement?

Answer (score 16):

Here is a DROP INDEX IF EXISTS procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS drop_index_if_exists $$
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_index_if_exists(in theTable varchar(128), in theIndexName varchar(128) )
BEGIN
 IF((SELECT COUNT(*) AS index_exists FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() and table_name =
theTable AND index_name = theIndexName) > 0) THEN
   SET @s = CONCAT('DROP INDEX ' , theIndexName , ' ON ' , theTable);
   PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
   EXECUTE stmt;
 END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This code was created based on the procedure from here: [Determining if MySQL table index exists before creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626645/determining-if-mysql-table-index-exists-before-creating)

Answer (score 3):

I tweaked answers found here and else where to come up with the following sprocs for dropping & creating indexes. Note that the AddTableIndex sproc can drop the index if need be. They also accept a schema name which was critical for my uses.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS migrate.DropTableIndex //

CREATE PROCEDURE migrate.DropTableIndex
    (
        in schemaName varchar(128) -- If null use name of current schema;
        , in tableName varchar(128) -- If null an exception will be thrown.
        , in indexName varchar(128) -- If null an exception will be thrown.
    )
BEGIN
    SET schemaName = coalesce(schemaName, schema());
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) AS index_exists FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = schemaName and table_name = tableName AND index_name = indexName) > 0) THEN
        SET @s = CONCAT('DROP INDEX `' , indexName , '` ON `' , schemaName, '`.`', tableName, '`');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END IF;
END //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS migrate.AddTableIndex//

CREATE PROCEDURE migrate.AddTableIndex
    ( 
        IN schemaName varchar(128) -- If null use name of current schema;
        , IN tableName varchar(128) -- If null an exception will be thrown.
        , IN indexName varchar(128) -- If null an exception will be thrown.
        , IN indexDefinition varchar(1024) -- E.g. '(expireTS_ ASC)'
        , IN ifPresent ENUM('leaveUnchanged', 'dropAndReplace') -- null=leaveUnchanged.
        , OUT outcome tinyint(1) -- 0=unchanged, 1=replaced, 4=added.
    )
    BEGIN

    DECLARE doDrop tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE doAdd tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE tmpSql varchar(4096) DEFAULT '';

    SET schemaName = coalesce(schemaName, schema());
    SET ifPresent = coalesce(ifPresent, 'leaveUnchanged');
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE  table_schema = schemaName AND table_name = tableName AND index_name = indexName) THEN
        IF (ifPresent = 'leaveUnchanged') THEN
            SET doDrop = 0;
            SET doAdd = 0;
            SET outcome = 0;
            ELSEIF (ifPresent = 'dropAndReplace')
            THEN
            SET doDrop = 1;
            SET doAdd = 1;
            SET outcome = 1;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SET doDrop = 0;
        SET doAdd = 1;
        SET outcome = 4;
    END IF;

    IF (doDrop = 1) THEN
        SET tmpSql = concat( 'alter table `', schemaName, '`.`', tableName, '` drop index `', indexName, '` ');
        SET @sql = tmpSql;
        PREPARE tmp_stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE tmp_stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE tmp_stmt;
    END IF;

    IF (doAdd = 1) THEN
        SET tmpSql = concat( 'alter table `', schemaName, '`.`', tableName, '` add index `', indexName, '` (', indexDefinition, ')');
        SET @sql = tmpSql;
        PREPARE tmp_stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE tmp_stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE tmp_stmt;
    END IF;

    END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Nicely done, just tapped this for a migration script! :) You might want to utilize some _ characters in the procedure names, tho ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar with using SELECT IF() statement in MySQL.

```
select if (
    exists(
        select distinct index_name from information_schema.statistics 
        where table_schema = 'schema_db_name' 
        and table_name = 'tab_name' and index_name like 'index_1'
    )
    ,'select ''index index_1 exists'' _______;'
    ,'create index index_1 on tab_name(column_name_names)') into @a;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

The advantage of using if() statement is that, it doesn’t need a stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will helpful to you drop your existing index.

```
        DELIMITER //
        CREATE PROCEDURE dropIndexing
        ()
        BEGIN

        IF EXISTS(
                    SELECT * FROM information_schema.statistics 
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
                    AND `table_name`='mytable' 
                    AND `index_name` = 'myindex'
                )
        THEN
        ALTER TABLE `mytable` DROP INDEX `myindex`;
        END IF;

        END //
        DELIMITER ;

        CALL dropIndexing();
        DROP PROCEDURE dropIndexing;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench version 6.3 (MySql fork MariaDb)

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS FK_customer__client_school__school_id ON dbname.tablename;
```

Comment: This works well on MariaDB. Workbench highlights the 'if' as if it is an error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with some of the solutions presented here. This is what I came up with:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myschema.create_index_if_not_exists $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myschema.create_index_if_not_exists(in p_tableName VARCHAR(128), in p_indexName VARCHAR(128), in p_columnName VARCHAR(128) )
BEGIN

PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT @indexCount := COUNT(1) from information_schema.statistics WHERE `table_name` = ? AND `index_name` = ?';
SET @table_name = p_tableName;
SET @index_name = p_indexName;
EXECUTE stmt USING @table_name, @index_name;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- select @indexCount;

IF( @indexCount = 0 ) THEN
  SELECT 'Creating index';
  SET @createIndexStmt = CONCAT('CREATE INDEX ', p_indexName, ' ON ', p_tableName, ' ( ', p_columnName ,')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @createIndexStmt;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Use it as follows:

```
call myschema.create_index_if_not_exists('MyTable','end_time_index','end_time');
```

This was tested on MAC OS X 10.8.2 with MySQL 5.5.24 and on Windows 7 with MySQL 5.5.21

Comment: when you select from information_schema, you should also specify the db....  

SELECT @indexCount := COUNT(1) from information_schema.statistics WHERE table_schema='DB' .......

Otherwise you could pick out indexes from different DBs that have the same table and index name - caught me out.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround for the `DROP INDEX IF EXISTS`, that is missing in MySQL and MariaDB versions before `v10.1.4`. You can also use it for every other statement you want, that should be depend on the existence of an `INDEX` (e.g. for `SELECT "info: index exists."` like in the example below).

```
-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
INTO
    @INDEX_my_index_ON_TABLE_my_table_EXISTS
FROM
    `information_schema`.`statistics`
WHERE
    `table_schema` = 'my_database'
    AND `index_name` = 'my_index'
    AND `table_name` = 'my_table'
;
SET @statement := IF(
    @INDEX_my_index_ON_TABLE_my_table_EXISTS > 0,
    -- 'SELECT "info: index exists."',
    'DROP INDEX `my_index` ON `my_table`',
    'SELECT "info: index does not exist."'
);
PREPARE statement FROM @statement;
EXECUTE statement;
```