# How to make DROP INDEX IF EXISTS for mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to DROP INDEX in mysql with option IF EXISTS but I have found nothing that make it works.

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_name ON table_name;
```

Anyone has any hint?

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480148/how-can-i-employ-if-exists-for-creating-or-dropping-an-index-in-mysql

Comment: On recent mysql versions this works. I just tried it myself and dropped the index.

Answer (score 11):

I do not see any straight-forward way to `DROP INDEX` using `IF EXISTS`.
As a workaround, I wrote the following Procedure, which works for me.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DropIndexIfExists`(
    IN i_table_name VARCHAR(128),
    IN i_index_name VARCHAR(128)
    )
    BEGIN

    SET @tableName = i_table_name;
    SET @indexName = i_index_name;
    SET @indexExists = 0;

    SELECT 
        1
    INTO @indexExists FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = @tableName
            AND INDEX_NAME = @indexName;

    SET @query = CONCAT(
        'DROP INDEX ', @indexName, ' ON ', @tableName
    );
    IF @indexExists THEN
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
    END
```

Comment: you could put your `SET @query...` inside the `IF`. Nitpick, but why would it run otherwise ? :p

Comment: update if multiple databases : 

`...
SELECT 1
INTO @indexExists
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE INDEX_SCHEMA = database()
  AND TABLE_NAME = @tableName
  AND INDEX_NAME = @indexName LIMIT 1;
...
`

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
create procedure DeleteIndex()
begin

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
            AND INDEX_NAME = 'IndexName' AND INDEX_SCHEMA='DbName') THEN
   ALTER TABLE  TableName DROP index THead2;
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score -4):

This is how you can drop index if exists in Laravel:

```
Schema::table("table_name", function (Blueprint $table) {
    $indexes = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableIndexes("table_name");
    foreach ($indexes as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == "index_name") {
            $table->dropIndex("index_name");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: OP has no tag for laravel / php but only MySql. This answer would unlikely help the OP.