# How I can drop an index if exist using django migrations.RunSQL and MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations

I'm trying to drop an index using migrations.RunSQL but I having the issue that doesn't exist, is there a way to Drop an index only in the case of exist? Something like migrations.RunSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_id ON table").

1. Django 1.8.18
2. MySQL 5.6

Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I employ "if exists" for creating or dropping an index in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480148/how-can-i-employ-if-exists-for-creating-or-dropping-an-index-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Since `IF EXISTS` is not supported in indexing by MySQL, you may want to write your own migration:

```
def drop_index_if_exists(apps, schema_editor):
    # access to the connection since schema_editor.execute does not return the cursor
    with schema_editor.connection.cursor() as cursor:
       cursor.execute("SHOW INDEX FROM table_name WHERE KEY_NAME = 'index_name'");
       exists = int(cursor.fetchone()) > 0
    # outside with to close the cursor
    if exists:
        schema_editor.execute("CREATE INDEX index_name ON ...")

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(drop_index_if_exists)
]
```

For consistency, you can write a `create_index_if_not_exists` method to un-apply the migration, and call it:

```
migrations.RunPython(drop_index_if_exists, create_index_if_not_exists)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I've used your idea to solve it :D

Comment: `exists = True if cursor.fetchone() else False` will always be `True`. You have to check the value

Comment: I've tested and if the query doesn't return rows, cursor.fetchone() is returning None:

`In [1]: from django.db import connection`

`In [2]: with connection.cursor() as cursor:`
`cursor.execute("SHOW INDEX FROM table1 WHERE KEY_NAME = 'index_name'")`
 `print cursor.fetchone()`
`(u'table1', 1L, u'index_name', 1L, u'index_name')`

`In [3]: with connection.cursor() as cursor:`
`cursor.execute("SHOW INDEX FROM table1 WHERE KEY_NAME = 'index_name2'")`
`print cursor.fetchone()`
`None`

Answer (score 0):

Here there is one solution, thank you for idea @alfonso.kim

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def drop_index_if_exists_and_create(apps, schema_editor):
    # access to the connection since schema_editor.execute does not return the cursor
    with schema_editor.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SHOW INDEX FROM table_name WHERE KEY_NAME = 'index_name'")
        exists = True if cursor.fetchone() else False
    # outside with to close the cursor
    if exists:
        schema_editor.execute("DROP INDEX index_name ON table_name")

    schema_editor.execute("CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(index_name(191))")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('table_name', ''),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(drop_index_if_exists_and_create)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a Transaction Error after executing your code:

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: Executing DDL statements while in a transaction on databases that can't perform a rollback is prohibited.
```

Django 2.5
MySql 5.7