# Is there any way to check if an index exists before you drop it?

Tags: mysql, database

**I get the following error:**

`Database error 1091 while doing query Can't DROP 'indexname'`; check that **column/key** exists

Is there any way to check if an index exists before you drop it without using stored procedures?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480148/how-can-i-employ-if-exists-for-creating-or-dropping-an-index-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Try by using SHOW INDEX

```
SHOW INDEX FROM Your_table
```

It will help to know index name of any column

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.statistics 
  WHERE table_schema = 'your_databasename'
    AND table_name = 'your_tablename' AND column_name = 'column_name'
```

For more [details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

DROP INDEX IF EXISTS unique_name ON mytable;

alter table mytable add unique unique_name (....)

unique_name is the constraints name and mytable is the table its applied on.

Hope this helps