# How to verify if index exists in a table before dropping the index on MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to check if a table contains an index.

My query didn`t compiled on MySql workbench. How can i test if on a table exists index to then drop only the index from it?

It would be something like that:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP INDEX medicos_cpf
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE INDEX = "medicos_cpf");
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480148/how-can-i-employ-if-exists-for-creating-or-dropping-an-index-in-mysql