# "if exists" in drop index clause

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

Using MySQL 8.0.21, Delphi 10.2 and FireDAC, how can I structure the following so that "if exists" doesn't cause an error?

```
ihQuery.SQL.Clear;
ihQuery.SQL.Add( 'drop index patno if exists on records' );
ihQuery.ExecSQL;
```

Thanks,
Jim Sawyer

Comment: Have you seen the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480148/how-can-i-employ-if-exists-for-creating-or-dropping-an-index-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I employ "if exists" for creating or dropping an index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480148/how-can-i-employ-if-exists-for-creating-or-dropping-an-index-in-mysql)