# DROP INDEX with condition as subquery(altering table)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

trying to drop the index if it exists

checking if the index exists- in the inner query

```
ALTER TABLE tableA DROP INDEX indexname WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableA' AND INDEX_NAME = 'indexname' AND INDEX_SCHEMA='schemaA')=1;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = tableA ' at line 1

in mysql version 5.7

Comment: ALTER TABLE syntax does not allow any subqueries. Execute unconditionally and ignore error if occured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I employ "if exists" for creating or dropping an index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480148/how-can-i-employ-if-exists-for-creating-or-dropping-an-index-in-mysql)

Comment: hi @Akina okay, how to do that ?

Comment: Simply `DROP INDEX indexname ON tablename;`.

Comment: For more information on how to interpret MySQL's 1064 syntax errors, [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql-error-1064/info).